# Выборка с группировкой

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть табличка (привожу основные поля, выбрать надо все) с полями:

`id|ticket|from|to|unix|status`

Выбираю из нее так:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE `to`=$userid GROUP BY `ticket` ORDER BY `status` ASC, `unix` DESC LIMIT $start,$num
```

Все было бы хорошо, но... выбираются сообщения как положено, с группировкой по полю `ticket`, но в выбранной группе находится сообщение с наименьшим `unix`, т.е. самое 1-е, а надо чтоб было последнее. Подскажите как реализовать данное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select *
from
  (
    select *
    from <table>
    where
      `to` = $userid
    order by
      `status` asc,
      `unix` desc
  ) t
group by`ticket`
limit $start, $num
```

Comment: Пасиб, завтра попробую.

Comment: Неа, не работает, точнее работает, но выбирает точно так же как и мой запрос, к сожалению. А еще, подскажите, что означает **`"t"`**? Просто 1-й раз вижу такое.

UPD: не, работает, просто косяк в записях БД был. Ответ принят, Спасибо! И все-таки расскажите про **`t`** ;)

Comment: Тут используется подзапрос, и вроде как, им надо обязательно давать псевдоним